# Extract specify date from a file line in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am having file `StandardDefaults.txt with contents below

```
 [MetaInfo]
 fileName="BUStandardDefaultsFile.dat"
 schemaVersion="2"
 schemaLocation="sftp:/var/app/napsgl/cgdata/GLFSUTN1/intfc/dsmtout/ISG/Schema/BUStandardDefaultsFileSchema_02.json"
 generationTime="2023-06-13T10:19:13.060606"
 process_time"2023-06-14T08:29:13.060606"
 recordsCount=1041
```

I need to extract date associated with `generationTime` value
Expected output:

```
 2023-06-13
```

I tried using `grep` to get `generationTime` from the file. But I need help in extract just the date value. I want to store the date value in a string. Then it will be used for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'["T]' '/^generationTime/ {print $3}' StandardDefaults.txt
2023-06-13
```

This tells `awk` to use either `"` or `T` as the field separator, then prints the third field on any input line starting with `generationTime`

Why the third field? Because there's a capital `T` in `generationTime` (so everything before that is $1); the second field, $2, is everything from there to the first `"` character; and the third field, $3, is everything from there to the next `T`.

```
generation   T  ime=   "  2023-06-13   T  10:19:13.060606   "
    $1      FS   $2   FS      $3      FS        $4         FS   $5
```

FS stands for Field Separator.   $5 will be empty because there's nothing after the final `"` field-separator (but awk will still count it as being the fifth field on that line, so awk's field counter variable `NF` will equal 5...this isn't important here, but can be important for scripts that use `NF` in some way).

To store the output from awk (or any program that prints to stdout) in a variable, use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), e.g.:

```
$ myvar=$(awk -F'["T]' '/^generationTime/ {print $3}' StandardDefaults.txt)

$ echo $myvar
2023-06-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` you can extract the part you want as follows:

```
sed -n 's/.*generationTime="\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)T.*/\1/p' StandardDefaults.txt
```

Or , the shorter variant is using `grep -Po` Perl-compatible Regex

```
grep -Po '(?<=generationTime=")[^T]*' StandardDefaults.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't for the missing `=` between `process_time` and its value, that would very much look like the type of INI file that php's `parse_ini_file()` recognises, and you could do:

```
php -r '
  $ini = parse_ini_file($argv[1], true);
  echo $ini["MetaInfo"]["generationTime"] . PHP_EOL;
  ' -- your-file.ini
```

To get that into a shell variable:

```
time=$(
  php -r '
    $ini = parse_ini_file($argv[1], true);
    echo $ini["MetaInfo"]["generationTime"];
  ' -- your-file.ini
)
```

as usual. You can then remove the `T...` part with `${time%%T*}` or strip it in php with:

```
date=$(
  php -r '
    $ini = parse_ini_file($argv[1], true);
    echo stristr($ini["MetaInfo"]["generationTime"], "T", true);
  ' -- your-file.ini
)
```

It would also be valid [TOML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOML), so you could use `tomlq` (a frontend to `jq` shipped with `yq`):

```
time=$(tomlq -r '.MetaInfo.generationTime' your-file.ini)
```

```
date=$(tomlq -r '.MetaInfo.generationTime|sub("T.*"; "")' your-file.toml)
```

Most programming languages have modules to parse TOMLs. Since 3.11, `python3` has one shipped by default:

```
date=$(python3 -c '
import tomllib
import sys
c = tomllib.load(sys.stdin.buffer)
print(c["MetaInfo"]["generationTime"].partition("T")[0])
' < your-file.toml
)
```

There are a few for perl though generally not installed by default. For instance, with `TOML::Tiny`:

```
date=$(
  perl -0777 -MTOML::Tiny -ne '
    print from_toml($_)->{MetaInfo}->{generationTime} =~ s/T.*//r
  ' your-file.toml
)
```

Note that the fact that those time stamps have no timezone indication suggest they may be in UTC, meaning that the corresponding date part may be different  from that in local time.

For instance, at the time I write this, it's `2023-06-16T06:45:10` UTC, but that's `2023-06-15T23:45:10` in Los Angeles USA.

To get the corresponding `$local_date` for a UTC timestamp such as `2023-06-13T10:19:13.060606` stored in `$time`, in `zsh` for instance:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs epoch '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' ${time%.*} &&
  strftime -s local_date %Y-%m-%d $epoch
```

For me in the `Europe/London` timezone, for `2023-06-13T10:19:13.060606` that gives `2023-06-13`, but for someone in `Pacific/Midway` for instance, that gives `2023-06-12`.

`jq` (and therefore `tomlq`) can also do date parsing and formatting (though that's not stable yet according to the man page), so that could be:

```
local_date=$(
   tomlq -r '.MetaInfo.generationTime |
               sub("\\.\\d+$"; "") |
               strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") |
               mktime |
               strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d")' your-file.toml
)
```